# Rename file with a value stored in Variable in Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel

I have a file and want to rename the file with and get the name from

cellObj.value

```
    os.rename(r'C:\Users\Com\Downloads\Software 02E - Installed software on a specific computer.xlsx',r'C:\Users\Com\Downloads\OUTPUT.xlsx')
```

Need change Output by value in Cellobj   (Example value: BPTPC0132)

Answer (score 0):

Reading a cell value from a excel file is no problem - from your question I cant get which cell you want to read your filename from so I assume the first cell in your first sheet for now:

```
import xlrd

xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("insertyourfilepathhere")
sheet_names = xl_workbook.sheet_names()
xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
cell = xl_sheet.cell(0,0)
output = cell.value
```

You can then use the output variable for saving your file.

Comment: No, in the above line of code how can i replace OUTPUT by the value in Cellobj.

Comment: I am working on a batch file that will map the shared drive(s) from different site, So first user has to pass an argument to select the site then to select which drive he wants there are three options Global(press G), Common(Press C) or Both(Press B) As i am new to Scripting and only use it when needed so i was able to do the site selection and mapping all(as in code below).

@echo off SET /P Site=Which site you want to map please type SITE CODE?

if /I %Site% == BPT (net use * \loc1\common && net use * \loc1\global)

if /I %Site% == LIV (net use * \loc2\global && net use * \loc2\common)

Answer (score 0):

This format worked for me

```
workbook.save(cellObj.value+".xlsx")
```